# Unpacking list read from JSON file to function call

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I have a JSON file containing the following lines:

```
{
    "manager": {
        "Community Developer" : 123,
        "Discord Administrator" : 456
    }
}
```

I am reading it by calling the my read_json function which uses the json module to load the file into a dict. Then I used list comprehension to create a list out of the dict items like so:

`item_list = [x for tup in permissions["manager"].items() for x in tup]`

And then I wanted to unpack that list to use in a function call from discord.py.

`@commands.has_any_role(*item_list)`

Unfortunately this is when things stopped to work. The discord decorator always seems to return False even though I clearly have the mentioned roles on my server. When I try to declare the list of roles as list of string in my code directly and unpack it, it works.
Does not work: item_list created with data read from file and list comprehension. Does work: defining the list directly: `item_list = ["Community Developer",123,"Discord Administrator",456]`

Both lists contain the exact same items and are in the same order. Unpacking them to print results in the same list being printed twice. The only difference is the way they were created.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to just look up and point to the key-pair value with a loop instead of unpacking the entire thing out every single time? I imagine that if your list of items get sufficiently big enough, it's a huge waste of memory.

Comment: That would be the case if I only needed one key,value pair but I need all of them as arguments. The decorator is checking the users roles and therefore has to know all roles possible.

Comment: But then you could just use an iterator for the dictionary with something like `if role in author.roles` in the iterator?